# On *any* event discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to run a certain block of code for *every* event. I figured that it would probably be easiest if there was something like `on_any_event`. However, I can't seem to find anything in the docs or on the web. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this, and if so, how?

Other Info:

- discord.py-rewrite

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be able to modify the libary somewhere around here https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py#L305 in `_run_event` or `dispatch` to do what you want but not certain.

Comment: what do you want to do. Maybe it can be done without an on_any_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

Most of the events in discord.py, afaik, is "handlers" for sockets responses.
You can try to use `on_socket_response(message)` event. This should be enough for all websocket-based events.

If you need literally **any** event, you can try overwrite `dispatch` function in child class, and use this class as your's bot's class.
In example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def dispatch(self, event_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().dispatch("event", event_name)
        super().dispatch(event_name, *args, **kwargs)

bot = MyBot(command_prefix="!")
```

This will dispatch additional event on any event

```py
@bot.event
async def on_event(event_name):
    print(f"{event_name} is dispatched")
```